# What is the keyword "license" used for in python?

Tags: python

I just went to use "license" as a variable name and it became highlighted to indicate that it was a reserved word, what is "license" used for?

Comment: It is not a keyword, but a builtin function; you could have just run the shell and type it to figure it out :)

Comment: It's *not* mentioned in the list of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), but *is* mentioned in the list of [built-in constants](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a keyword, [it's a constant added by the *site* module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) (some others are `copyright` and `credits`). If you want to know what it does, try:

```
print license
>>> Type license() to see the full license text
```

then if you type

```
license()
```

output will be:

> ## A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE
>
> Python was created in the early 1990s by Guido van Rossum at Stichting
>   Mathematisch Centrum (CWI, see http://www.cwi.nl) in the Netherlands
>   as a successor of a language called ABC.  Guido remains Python's
>   principal author, although it includes many contributions from others.
>
> In 1995, Guido continued his work on Python at the Corporation for
>   National Research Initiatives (CNRI, see http://www.cnri.reston.va.us)
>   in Reston, Virginia where he released several versions of the
>   software.
>
> In May 2000, Guido and the Python core development team moved to
>   BeOpen.com to form the BeOpen PythonLabs team.  In October of the same
>   year, the PythonLabs team moved to Digital Creations (now Zope
>   Corporation, see http://www.zope.com).  In 2001, the Python Software
>   Foundation (PSF, see http://www.python.org/psf/) was formed, a
>   non-profit organization created specifically to own Python-related
>   Intellectual Property.  Zope Corporation is a sponsoring member of the
>   PSF.
>
> All Python releases are Open Source (see http://www.opensource.org for
>   Hit Return for more, or q (and Return) to quit:

Comment: 6 years later... don't know how I managed to log back into this account. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`license` is one of the [built-in *constants*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html?highlight=license#constants-added-by-the-site-module) added by the [`site` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site).

It's use is entirely within the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> license
See http://www.python.org/2.7/license.html
```

Other such objects are `credits` and `copyright`, plus the `quit()` and `exit()` functions.

If you are curious as to its implementation, see the [`setcopyright()` function source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/site.py#l426).

Comment: Well, `license()` and `quit()` etc.. works perfectly in non interactive mode, as functions.

Comment: @GuillaumeLebreton: sure, but they are rarely *useful* outside of the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a reserved word in Python: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

It's a built-in function; try running it in an interactive shell:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> license
Type license() to see the full license text
>>> license()
A. HISTORY OF THE SOFTWARE
==========================

Python was created in the early 1990s by Guido van Rossum at Stichting
Mathematisch Centrum (CWI, see http://www.cwi.nl) in the Netherlands
as a successor of a language called ABC.  Guido remains Python's
principal author, although it includes many contributions from others.

In 1995, Guido continued his work on Python at the Corporation for
National Research Initiatives (CNRI, see http://www.cnri.reston.va.us)
in Reston, Virginia where he released several versions of the
software.

In May 2000, Guido and the Python core development team moved to
BeOpen.com to form the BeOpen PythonLabs team.  In October of the same
year, the PythonLabs team moved to Digital Creations (now Zope
Corporation, see http://www.zope.com).  In 2001, the Python Software
Foundation (PSF, see http://www.python.org/psf/) was formed, a
non-profit organization created specifically to own Python-related
Intellectual Property.  Zope Corporation is a sponsoring member of
the PSF.

All Python releases are Open Source (see http://www.opensource.org for
Hit Return for more, or q (and Return) to quit:
```

Comment: It's not even really a builtin, it only exists at the interactive interpreter and is defined in `site.py`.

Comment: Interesting, that's not what the distributed 2.7.3 source would print.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Any code can put anything into `__builtin__`, I use "builtin" in the sense of http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html and the like. Stuff from the interpreter core.